# automatically create mini-website from Markdown files?

Tags: css, markdown, dropbox, wiki, jekyll

Is there a tool that will automatically generate a mini-website---with automatically generated navigation---from locally-stored Markdown files?

I'm envisioning a service that will integrate with my Dropbox, look at the file structure, look at the Markdown files, and automatically create a clean little site with my pages and with hierarchical navigation.

Full-text search would be cool but not required.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 6):

The general term for the tool you speak of is called a **static site generator**. They are a new trend in web publishing and there are literally tons of them and new ones coming out all the time. Most of them have markdown support so you will have a task in choosing the best one.

My introduction to the topic was reading this blog post, [*An Introduction to Static Site Generators*](http://www.mickgardner.com/2012/12/an-introduction-to-static-site.html) by Michael Gardner. If you're interested in the subject I would recommend giving it a read. It discusses the advantages to using such a strategy over a dynamic one, and also compares multiple generators. The comparison includes and ends up focusing on Jekyll which is probably the most popular static site generator as far as I can tell.

Also you will probably want to read [*Node Based Static Site Generators*](http://blog.bmannconsulting.com/node-static-site-generators/) by Boris Mann who is also looking into Dropbox support as well. I have been looking into different static site generators as well and a few that I have noticed, but haven't had a chance to look at much:

- [**Hexo**](http://zespia.tw/hexo/)
- [**node-romulus**](https://github.com/felixge/node-romulus)

Answer (score 4):

I think [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) could do it. Jekyll is a blog-aware, static site generator in Ruby and you could host it direct on github if you want.

Comment: Thanks. Are there preexisting Jekyll templates, with beautifully designed layout files, that I could just borrow and plug into? Or do I have to design from scratch?

Comment: i think if you use github pages there are desigens to select otherwise you may have a look at http://jekyllbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of [StackEdit](http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/), a Markdown editor that can be used as a blogging client. You can use it to write your document and directly publish it in HTML format to your blog (Blogger, WordPress, Tumblr or Jekyll via through GitHub).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Docusaurus**](https://v2.docusaurus.io/) the open source project from **Facebook**!

> Simply write docs and blog posts with Markdown/MDX and **Docusaurus** will publish a set of static HTML files ready to serve.

I've wrote a simple **[plugin](https://github.com/acrobit/docusaurus-plugin-auto-sidebars)** for Docusaurus that automatically generates the sidebar menu from file/folder structure so you even don't have to define them manually!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Skrivr does just that: http://skrivr.com/